# Ionic Cordova build fails with 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

My Ionic app build on OSX suddenly started failing with the below error. I have not done anything, other letting go through a Xcode update. No code change on my end. I reverted to a previous production build and tried to rebuild from there but same error.

No change in the code indicates that the build process is broken

1. Should I revert to the previous Xcode version (but how?).
2. Should I update Ionic / Cordova? Will do that most likely.
3. Should I just check out my project again and rebuild from a clean
   folder?

I see from other posts that might be a promise issue where it's trying to resolve a promise from a buggy object.

```
Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at /Users/me/app/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/list-emulator-build-targets:54:45
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/me/app/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/list-emulator-build-targets:52:44
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/me/app/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/list-emulator-build-targets:50:57
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/me/app/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/list-emulator-build-targets:45:28
    at _fulfilled (/Users/me/app/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at /Users/me/app/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/me/app/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
```

```
ionic --version
4.10.3

"cordova-android": "7.1.4",
"cordova-ios": "4.5.5",

Xcode v 11.1
```

Comment: Can u check in xcode if you can build your project ? Sometimes this error came from the signing  profiles . Try to see if you have error in the signing and capabilities options (xcode).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that later.

Comment: Yea, I still can build the project. It fails after the copy stage, so I can assume that it has been properly copied? The code is obfuscated, hard to tell my changes made it.   Adding visual changes as an indicator. Regardless, this is no good solution if it turns out it works.

Comment: Changes are copied but the whole debug build process fails. OK for now, but will search for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently xcode 11 has some conflict with a validation in the file list-emulator-build-targets. 
You need to execute this command.

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios
ionic cordova platform add ios@latest
```

Make sure that you get the cordova-ios version >= 5.0.0